# do(ggsave...) appears to work but throws an error

Tags: r, ggplot2

Data for reproducible example:

```
DF <- data.frame(plotName=c(rep("bread",20),rep("cheese",20)),
                 mould=rnorm(40,2))
```

I generated a series of plots with a command of the form:

```
PlotsDF <- DF %>% group_by(plotName) %>% 
do(plots=
   ggplot(.,aes(mould)) + 
       geom_histogram(bins=10) + 
       ggtitle(.$plotName)
  )
```

Then attempted to save them with:

```
PlotsDF %>% do(ggsave(plot = .$plots,
                     filename = paste0("./graphics/prefix_" , .$plotName , ".png")
               ))
```

This appears to work fine, the files are saved, but when it finishes throws an  error,

the traceback returned is:

```
Error: Results 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... must be data frames, not NULL
15.     stop(cnd)
14.     .abort(text)
13.     glubort(NULL, ..., .envir = parent.frame())
12.     bad("Results {bad} must be data frames, not {first_bad_class}", bad = fmt_comma(which(!data_frame)), first_bad_class = fmt_classes(out[[1]][[which.min(data_frame)]]))
11.     label_output_dataframe(NULL, out, groups(.data))
10.     do.rowwise_df(., ggsave(plot = .$plots, filename = paste0("./graphics/prefix_", .$plotName, ".png"), width = 16, height = 9))
9.  do(., ggsave(plot = .$plots, filename = paste0("./graphics/prefix_", .$plotName, ".png"), width = 16, height = 9))
8.  function_list[[k]](value)
7.  withVisible(function_list[[k]](value))
6.  freduce(value, `_function_list`)
5.  `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
4.  eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
3.  eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
2.  withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
1.  PlotsDF %>% do(ggsave(plot = .$plots, filename = paste0("./graphics/prefix_", .$plotName, ".png"), width = 16, height = 9))
```

This becomes a problem then knitting the notebook as it stops the process. Any ideas what's causing the error and how to get rid of it?

Comment: Isn't the problem the `filename = paste0("./graphics/prefix_" , .$plotName , ".png")` part? I tried it as `filename = paste0(.$plotName, ".png")` and it worked.

Comment: Interesting that is not working for me, any idea why it might be working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem Arises from `do()` expecting somthing to return as a data frame this can be avoided by asigning the return of `ggsave()` to a value:

```
PlotsDF %>% do(out=ggsave(plot = .$plots,
                 filename = paste0("./graphics/prefix_" , .$plotName , ".png")
           ))
```

Which then returns a dataframe full of NULLs which can be discarded - bit of a hacky solution but it works.